# Load variable data from click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple links like:

```
<a id="en">EN</a> <a id="fr">FR</a> etc...
```

and the following code:

```
$en = 'This is some data that should appear in the textarea for EN';
$de = '';
$es = '';
$fr = '';
$it = '';
$pl = '';
$pt = '';
$zhcn = '';
$zhtw = '';
$jp = '';

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(e){

        $code = $ + $(this).attr('id');

        $('textarea.code').val( $code );

    });

});
```

What I want to do is when the user clicks a link, get the data from the related variable and put it inside the textarea with the class of code. Currently I'm just getting: `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}en`

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use an Object instead to group this information.

```
var data = {
  "en" : "This is some data that should appear in the textarea for EN",
  "de" : "",
  "es" : "",
  "fr" : "",
  "it" : "",
  ...
}
```

In this way you won't need to mess with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```
var str = data[ this.id ];
```

Comment: Heres a fiddle for your code http://jsfiddle.net/p3uQT/ - though I left the `$` in the variable names

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    var $code = "$" + $(this).attr('id');

    $('textarea.code').val( window[$code] );

});
```

Assuming the variables are global.

Here's [a demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMXFn/) (provided by wirey).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo: `$ + $(this).attr('id');` should be `"$" + $(this).attr('id');`. But that's not the real problem.

You're evaluating the input as a literal string, not as a variable. So the value of `$code` is getting set to the literal string "$en", instead of the value of your `$en` variable.

You could use `eval($code)` to do it, BUT THAT IS A VERY BAD IDEA. Don't do that. What you should do instead is arrange your variables such that you can access them by name. There's more than one way to do this, but here's how I'd do it:

```
var data = {
    en: 'This is some data that should appear in the textarea for EN',
    de: '',
    es: '',
    fr: '',
    it: '',
    pl: '',
    pt: '',
    zhcn: '',
    zhtw: '',
    jp: ''
};

$(document).ready(function(){    

    $('a').click(function(e){    

        var $code = data[$(this).attr('id')];    

        $('textarea.code').val( $code );    

    });    
});
```